# Multiple headers in REST call giving #415 error

Tags: javascript, rest

I have this REST request that I can't seem to get to work correctly.
This is just the "login" to the resource but I assume the same problem will occur as I move forward.

```
var bodyinfo = {
    ApiKey: "#theapikey",
    Username: "#theusername",
    Password: "#thepassword" };

fetch('{base-url}/user/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        mode: 'no-cors',
        body: JSON.stringify(bodyinfo)
    })
    .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });
```

I've tried to stringify the headers as well but I always end up getting 'Status Code: 415 Unsupported Media Type'.

The HTTPRequest works fine when testing with either Postman or when I run it through a HTTPRequest in WebStorm.

Comment: ApiKey: "#theapikey}", you forgot to remove }

Comment: I missed this but this was added by accident while posting the question. Edited the post accordingly. Thanks for the heads up.